# Mail traffic between MailDev container and Django container delivers Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, docker

Mail traffic between MailDev container and Django container delivers

> [Errno 111] Connection refused

Email traffic to console backend works, so the function should be correct.

```
send_mail(
            'Subject here',
            'Here is the message.',
            'from@example.com',
            ['to@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False
        )
```

After I switched to SMTP backend and started MailDev in Container,  I got:

> [Errno 111] Connection refused

in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

in Shell:

```
sudo docker run -p 1080:80 -p 1025:25 --name maildev djfarrelly/maildev
```

**My Docker Containers are:**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES

a46040dd1259        djfarrelly/maildev   "bin/maildev --web..."   11 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:1025->25/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1080->80/tcp   maildev

4fed036f92d4        exposee              "/usr/src/start.sh"      42 minutes ago      Up 42 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp                       exposee

2c2cf7ce19e9        winauth              "gunicorn -b 0.0.0..."   43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       127.0.0.1:9876->9876/tcp                     winauth

afe4a449aa01        postgres             "docker-entrypoint..."   44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes       127.0.0.1:5432->5432/tcp                     postgres
```

**My Settings in settings.py are:**

```
EMAIL_HOST = CONFIG.get('EMAIL_HOST', '127.0.0.1')

EMAIL_PORT = CONFIG.get('EMAIL_PORT', 1025)

EMAIL_USE_TLS = CONFIG.get('EMAIL_USE_TLS', False)

EMAIL_USE_SSL = CONFIG.get('EMAIL_USE_SSL', False)
```

**My Configuration in config.json is:**

```
"EMAIL_HOST": "127.0.0.1",

"EMAIL_PORT": 1025,

"EMAIL_USE_TLS": false,

"EMAIL_USE_SSL": false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to connect from one container to another using `127.0.0.1`. This won't work are this address will correspond to the container sending the request.

For container to be able to inter-communicate, the standard way is to connect the containers to a common network.

```
sudo docker network create mail-net
sudo docker run --network main-net -p 1080:80 -p 1025:25 --name maildev djfarrelly/maildev
```

Connect the container sending the requests to the network:

```
docker network connect mail-net <container-name>
```

And change the host from `127.0.0.1` to `maildev`

```
EMAIL_HOST = CONFIG.get('EMAIL_HOST', 'maildev')
EMAIL_PORT = CONFIG.get('EMAIL_PORT', 25)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. Unfortunately, the website breaks off and I get a white screen after I tried to send an email. I've found that happens as soon as I enter something other than "EMAIL_HOST": "127.0.0.1". Do you know why this happens?